# memory free space is decreasing but available is increasing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, free

I am checking memory continuously by `free` command.

From three month ago. `free` space is decreasing continuously. From 70% to 30%, but `used` is not changed so much, `available` is getting increasing instead.

Is this a problem?? or How can I increase `free` space? from `available`?

```
$free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15854        1912        4522           5        9419       13618
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Comment: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't pay too much attention to the `free` memory because your applications can use pretty much all of the `available` memory.

The `free` RAM is not used by anything. `available` includes the `buffers/cache` which can be released by the kernel when/if needed. If you don't care about buffers/cache which can be very helpful as their minimize disk usage, you can run this:

```bsh
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Now you have evicted all your buffers/cache and you can enjoy as much `free` as possible.

> memory free space is decreasing but available is increasing

That's exactly what should be happening when you use applications and open files: the kernel tries to cache everything in RAM.